# wordpress posts/content in 2 languages

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I'm setting up a wordpress 3 blog and we need to be able to write and manage content/blog posts in two languages.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this? Are there any WP3 plugins that make this process possible?

The solutions should work on the latest version of wordpress (3.0 right now) and we would like to keep titles/keywords/description tags separate per language of the post for SEO reasons.

Answer (score 1):

http://wpml.org/ is a nice multi-language wordpress plugin and still actively maintained.

Comment: This is the best plugin for multi-language, and a great support network.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that will handle this. The one I'm more familiar with is xLanguage:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xlanguage/

It doesn't look like its developer updates it anymore, but people are saying that it works on WordPress 3.0.

I don't know if that handles tags/categories as well, though.